# Replace a string in a column with zero's

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in SQL Server table which has a mix of a string 'Wait' or numbers. How can I change this to a `0` (zero). There are 250,000 records with about 10,000 with the string.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one will replace string starts with 'WAIT'\

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMNNAME = 0
WHERE COLUMNNAME LIKE 'WAIT%'
```

or 
this one will check and replace string contains  'WAIT' anywhere

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMNNAME = 0
WHERE COLUMNNAME LIKE '%WAIT%'
```

before update please check the result set is correct or not by using below select query

```
select COLUMNNAME from TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMNNAME LIKE 'WAIT%'
select COLUMNNAME from TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMNNAME LIKE '%WAIT%'
```

Comment: Very good replies and answers. I will follow these and correct... Fingers crossed  .. Chris

Comment: This works but I tried with a second column to remove NULL entries as follows UPDATE
mytable
SET
c_per= '0'
WHERE
 c_per IS NULL    this does not work and I get a Changed database context to 'c_per'   error/warning

Comment: can you please mention datatype of that column

Comment: The issue has been resolved … thanks Samir for your help again

Answer (score 1):

Do you need below -

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
SET COLUMN = 0
WHERE UPPER(COLUMN) LIKE '%WAIT%'
```